# Batch montage of images with paging

Tags: scripting, image-processing, imagemagick, montage

I have hundreds of images (png), sorted by name.
They all have different sizes, but the same print resolution is to be used.

I want to montage them in column, only one per row, possibly centered, and so that when the total height of the montage reaches an A4 paper height (~30cm) it starts again on another page..

I tried to do it with the montage command of the imageMagick suite.. but I can't make it page based on height and not the nubmer of images (because images are of different sizes, pages might contain a different number of images..)

Any idea?

Comment: I took a look at the man page for montage and ran screaming for the hills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the total height of the montage reaches an A4 paper height (~30cm) it starts again on another page

I assume that that "another page" actually means "another image".

You need to compute the height (physical) of each image, and do some basic math. This seems a task well suited to [PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) . If you are not confortable with Perl, you might try another [ImageMagick interface](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) in your prefered language.

Comment: I did it with a ruby script.. it was pretty easy still I think it should be implemented in imageMagick..